# Change C thread parameters while executing the thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I need to update a parameter of a thread function dynamically. The function receives 3 parameters, and :

- An exit flag (int)
- The mutex parameter for the exit flag
- An structure for a stock market

lib/concurrency_layer.c :

```c
void * operation_executer(void *args){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&marketMutex);

   struct exec_info *execData = args;        //Parsing data from parameters
   stock_market *market = execData->market;  // Create stock market structure
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&marketMutex);

   pthread_mutex_lock(execData->exit_mutex);
   // Waits until exit flag it's 1
   while(*(execData->exit) == 0){           
        pthread_cond_wait(&exitCond, execData->exit_mutex);
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(execData->exit_mutex);

   pthread_mutex_lock(&marketMutex);

    struct operation op;
    while(operations_queue_empty(market->stock_operations) == 0){
            dequeue_operation(market->stock_operations, &op);
            process_operation(market, &op);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&marketMutex);
}
```

I've tried with a pthread conditional, but I don't know where to make the signal because, the exit flag changes in main function (in a different file):

```c
#include "include/concurrency_layer.h";

int main(){
   exit = 0;
    exec_info info_ex1;
    info_ex1.market = &market_madrid;
    info_ex1.exit = &exit;
    info_ex1.exit_mutex = &exit_mutex;



    pthread_create(&(tid[1]), NULL, &operation_executer, (void*) &info_ex1);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&exit_mutex);
    exit = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&exit_mutex);

    pthread_join(tid[1],&res);
}
```

The idea is that function must execute when `exit=1`.

I can add extra global variables, functions, mutex, conditionals... in lib/concurrency_layer.h, but I can't modify include/concurrency_layer.h, so I cannot use a function for activating a signal.

Comment: A condition variable is a good choice for this job.  I don't understand what problem you perceive with using one.  Why does it matter in what source file the code that sets the exit flag resides?

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` is going to wait forever as you never signal the condition after setting the `exit` flag. After setting `exit` you need to call `pthread_cond_signal(&exitCond);` from your main thread. Additionally there is no need to obtain the mutex lock in the main thread to set the flag and signal the condition.

Comment: Using a global variable `exit` is going to lead to confusion if you use `<stdlib.h>` anywhere — it conflicts with the `exit()` function.  Choose a different, non-reserved name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `exit` here is the name of a local variable and of a structure member. Isn't `exit` only reserved for global names?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin — given `int main(){
   exit = 0;` there is no way that `exit` is a local variable.  Yes, if it was defined in `main()` (for example, using `int main(){
   int exit = 0;`) then you'd only have confusion to deal with.  You can use `exit` as a member (of a structure or union) OK, though it isn't particularly recommended.  But the global variable is appalling, and if it was a local variable, it is merely extremely unwise.  See [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thread is going to deadlock state at `pthread_cond_wait()` in `operation_executer()` because you are not calling `pthread_cond_singal()` anywhere in your program. If you are lucky and `exit = 1;` is executed first in `main()` before `while(*(execData->exit) == 0)`, it might work.

You need to make the following changes.

1. Call `pthread_cond_singal()` from main after making `exit = 1;` as below.

   `pthread_mutex_lock(&exit_mutex);
    exit = 1;
    pthread_cond_singal(&exitCond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&exit_mutex);`
2. You can change `while(*(execData->exit) == 0)` to `if(*(execData->exit) == 0)` in `operation_executer()` as you need to check the `exit` flag only once.